# Create a javascript pop-up with createElement

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I would like to create a pop-up when I press "details". I don't know how to deal with "createElement".

```js
let ul = document.createElement('ul');

let detail = document.createElement('details');
detail.appendChild(ul); // element du detail

let summary = document.createElement('div');
summary.appendChild(detail);

let colDetail = document.createElement('td');
colDetail.className = 'td-detail';
colDetail.appendChild(summary);
```

```html
<th>Détails</th>
```

Comment: _"I don't know how to deal with "createElement"."_ - and I don't know, what you are actually trying to say with that. If you don't know how the methods works - go read up on it, for example in the MDN. And if you have done that - well then give us a proper explanation, of what your actual problem with it is now.

Comment: When running your code, I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: ul is not defined`

Comment: let ul = document.createElement('ul');

Answer (score 0):

You can look into jquery popup overylay plugin.

https://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/

The instructions on how to make an overlay popup are great.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.addEventListener()` or `.onClick` methods on element.

- [MDN addEventLister Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [MDN onClick Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A popup in the page is called a modal.
The easiest way to do it is not to create the new element, but rather have it all along with a CSS-class that is hidden:

```
.nodisplay {
    display: none
}
```

Then you hide or show it removing the class with

```
element.classList.add('nodisplay')
```

or

```
element.classList.remove('nodisplay')
```